# Need some help converting C# method to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I am a C# guy who is desperately trying to learn C++ and port some old code over. Been doing OK so far but the following method has me stumped. If anyone could give me some pointers (sorry for pun) I would be grateful.

C# method:

```
public static string crappyEncryption(String userKey)    
{    
    StringBuilder eStr = new StringBuilder();    
    String key1 = "somehorriblelongstring";    
    String key2 = "someotherhorriblelongstring";    
    for (int i = 0; i < userKey.Length; i++)   
    {    
        eStr.Append(key2[key1.IndexOf(userKey[i])]);    
    }    
    return encodeTo64(eStr.ToString());    
}
```

`encodeTo64` is a local method which I have solved in C++. This weird method (if you were wondering) was a small encryption method I came up with that we could use mobile cross platform for non-essential string encryption.

Thanks very much

Comment: if your weird `encodeTo64` is an algorithm from Base64 family (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) then I wouldn't call it weird, it's just a way to deal with textual communications when you need to transfer binary data.

Comment: Is there something specific that has you stumped? This doesnt look too bad. The std::string type will be what you use in place of the string builder and string. std::string has an append function, and a find function to use in place of IndexOf.

Comment: miscommunication - I was referring to my crappyEncryption() method as wierd.  :)

Comment: I have got the code up to the loop going by using std:: string and std::wstring but I am getting an invalid conversion exception for the line within the loop: eStr = key2[key1.find(userKey[i])]; I have eStr defines as std::string *eStr and the key strings as std::wstring

Comment: If the purpose of porting the code is simply to learn C++, then sure. Generally, as a principle, porting code is a waste of productive time, when you could be wrapping the code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not gonna give you the whole code, but some pointers:

- a `StringBuilder` can be substituted by a `std::stringstream`.
- a `String` is a `std::string`
- it has the method `length()`, `find()` and `operator[]`.
- `std::stringstream` has `operator <<` for `Append`.
- `ToString` is `std::stringstream::str()`.
- you'll want to pass `userKey` by reference.

All concepts you don't understand can easily be found with a google search.